# Consume an AWS Private Api Gateway from another Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, vpc-endpoint

I have an private Api Gateway in Virginia region and an application in Canada region (same AWS account) which needs to consume the private API.

I have configured the peering between VPCs, the VPC Endpoint on my Canada VPC and updated the API Gateway resource policy.

When trying to consume the Private API from an instance in VPC Canada, I get the following error:

> ERROR: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccesible host. This service may not be available in the 'us-east-1' region
> [image]

Reading about the error, it seems that Endpoints are regional resources, so the API in Virginia would not be resolved by the Endpoint on Canada. So in that case, I wonder how can I communicate to a Private Api in another region.